# Local LAN connections always give a "connection timeout" error

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ftp

Local connections between devices do not work with my internet. Please correct me if "local LAN connections" is not the right term, I'm not very knowledgeable about networking. I'm referring to the device-to-device connections between devices connected to the same network. The three things I've noticed not working are FTP, my Wi-Fi printer, and local Minecraft servers; I've only recently realized these issues are likely related. Each one attempts to connect for about 15-20 seconds before giving a connection timeout error. I have tried extending the timeout on the applications and the router, nothing changes. I've looked through all configuration settings available on the router, but nothing I do seems to allow these connections. I think I've eliminated the possibility of my devices being the issue as I've taken them to school and they work as expected there. I've had the Minecraft issue since I got the game 6 years ago, and have since moved houses and been through 3 different routers. I noticed the printer issue upon trying to print something for the first time about a year ago (I don't print things often). I noticed the FTP issue a few years ago with one device and just assumed the device was faulty and gave up, but I tried to use FTP with a different device yesterday and it's doing the same thing. These issues occur with various Windows 10 laptops, an HP DeskJet Wi-Fi printer, a Nintendo Wii U, and a Nintendo New 3DS XL. My router model is an Actiontec T3200. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: One thought, check for identical mac addresses.

Comment: None of my devices have identical mac addresses. I would think that if they did, they wouldn't have worked on my school wifi.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, I seem to have solved this? I tried to enable more traffic-in ports on my router firewall and decided to try FTP again and it's working now. The ports I just enabled aren't even the ones being used (I had already enabled those a long time ago). Weird, but I guess my issue is solved.